# Posting markup/code as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with some very basic examples that use HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I'd like to be able to post the code for these examples as text on my website. I've tried using the the pre and code elements to wrap the block of text that represents the code.

Here is the site: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/jkinzel/examples/

The last small problem is that in certain instances, the < and > are being encoded as `&gt;` and `&lt;`. You see in the second example's code (under the JavaScript and CSS headings) that this is case, but only on certain occasions. Other times they are properly displayed as < and > (which is what I want).

Anyone have any ideas as to why this happens sometimes and not others?

Comment: It's a result of the text being encoded twice; that is, it's encoded once to turn the `<` and `>` characters into HTML entities, and then those are encoded again, which makes them stop working. That is, `&lt;` turns into `&amp;lt;` when it's encoded twice.

Comment: @Pointy Why isn't this posted as an answer?

Comment: @Pointy Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

Comment: @meagar well it's only half an answer; it's what's happening, but in this case, because the mechanism of how things get to the page is not described, it's impossible to say exactly how it's happening.

Comment: The way to stop it from happening is to not do it.  I don't know how your pages are put together, but at some point, if you see that effect, it means that something is re-encoding an already-encoded block of content.

Comment: @Pointy Additionally, if that were the case, would it not also encode the other elements? Notice in the 2nd example how `$('.tree-menu li &gt; ul').hide();` is incorrect, but a few lines later `$(this).html( $(this).html() == "<span>Expand</span>" ? "<span>Collapse</span>" : "<span>Expand</span>");` is posted correctly.

Comment: @Pointy the page is hand coded, so I have control over the code.

Comment: @Pointy Exactly. He asked *why* it happens, not how to fix it. The answer to why it happens is language agnostic: Double encoding.

Comment: @Pointy if you create an answer, I will make it correct. You got me on the right path. I changed the code inside those blocks to be mixed encoded/decoded so I get the proper output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment above:

It's a result of the text being encoded twice; that is, it's encoded once to turn the < and > characters into HTML entities, and then those are encoded again, which makes them stop working. That is, `&lt;` turns into `&amp;lt;` when it's encoded twice.

*More detail*: The most important characters to encode in order to show HTML as it looks in source form are "<" and "&"; generally people encode ">" too, though *usually* it's not a problem. (Actually, "&" by itself is also *usually* not a problem, but whatever.)  HTML entities look like "&foo;", where "foo" is some key.  Thus, when you encode text, you end up with "&foo;" all over the place. When you encode *again*, the "&" at the beginning of those little strings is re-encoded as "&".

Answer (score 2):

How about using something like [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) that will do this for you?